# Google explainable ai 429 error Rate of traffic exceeds serving capacity. Decrease your traffic or reduce the size of your model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to interpret an image prediction model using Google's explainable ai, but I get a 429 error. The model I want to interpret is a model that uses the mobilenet v3 large model and applies transfer learning.

**python code :**

```
ig_response = remote_ig_model.explain(instances)
```

**results :**

```
ValueError: Target URI https://asia-northeast1-        ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/cellimaging/models/A549_4/versions/v_ig_4:explain returns     HTTP 429 error.
Please check the raw error message: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Rate of traffic exceeds serving capacity. Decrease your traffic or reduce the size of your model: projects/842842301933/models/A549_4/versions/v_ig_4.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

When creating a serving model using ai-platform, the command is as follows.

**code :**

```
! gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $IG_VERSION --region='asia-northeast1' \
--model $MODEL \
--origin $export_path \
--runtime-version 2.2 \
--framework TENSORFLOW \
--python-version 3.7 \
--machine-type n1-highcpu-32 \
--explanation-method integrated-gradients \
--num-integral-steps 25
```

I got a 429 error and tried changing the machine-type (n1-standard-4 -> n1-highcpu-32), but the error is not resolved.

Comment: What's the size of the message that you send to your endpoint?

Comment: I used the image prediction model and image with (1024, 1024, 3) was sent to explanation model.  Do I need to reduce image size? I will try it.

Comment: I changed image size to (224, 224, 3) and it worked (no error). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look on this [troubleshoot section](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict#troubleshooting_online_prediction), your request can't be larger than 1.5Mb

> A single online prediction request must contain no more than 1.5 MB of data.

If you have an input of 1024,1024,3, your image size should be 3Mb (1024 x 1024 x 3 bytes) and therefore too big for the API.